Comparing my results with those of the previous studies
I would like to present the differences between the results of my study and those from other previous studies since I do not have any control/comparison group in my study design, but still want to highlight it.
However, it seems not as simple as I thought to conduct a comparison in such a way.
I mentioned the results of the existing studies in Literature review section which had the similar experimental set-ups, and then would like to highlight that my participants exhibited these differences compared with the results of those studies.
So far, I have gone like this for example: "My participants exhibited the value of 2, and the previous studies showed 1-1.5, so my participants have a greater value".
Of course, this sounds definitely unscientific and insignificant... and I heard from my advisor that I should not do in that way.
I want to know if there is any robust or statistically sound way to do such a comparison. If not, I would like to know what would be an alternative for those who are suffering from the problem like me.
Thank you all for your time for reading and answering in advance.

But can you replicate the previous result? Or you know the specific reason for such difference?

Hi, maybe I have written unclearly. Sorry for the confusion. With the "previous studies" or "existing studies" I meant the studies by other authors. So, replication is not available. When it comes to the reasons for the differences, I can just estimate it (but I am not sure if this reason for the difference is absolute) and was about to elaborate in discussion section "The difference is abc and I guess this is because xyz..."

But as far as I understood, the idea itself that I want to compare the results of the other studies with mines is defective, unless I do not have any certain robust statistical way to do it. My supervisor meant that I could refer to other studies that have done this way, if such a study exists, but I cannot find any...
